# How to change default notification sound (tri-tone) for *all* apps (via Terminal preferably)?

Tags: terminal, notifications, defaults, sonoma

My dog does *not* like the default `Tri-Tone` notification sound that all apps adopt as a default.

I've found the file itself:

`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AlertTones/Classic`

But rather than manipulate the file (which I'm not sure is possible, due to some weird permissions settings - even with `sudo`), I'd like to set some sort of default (using `defaults write`).

**EDIT:** The permissions issue is due to a read-only filesystem. I *think* it might be possible to bypass that in recovery mode, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Does anyone know if this is possible in MacOS 14.1?

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I don't get any sound with Notifications. Not for Calendar events, crash reports, or anything else that pops up in the right-hand corner. Not sure how, though.

Answer (score 4):

The operating system is sealed so every check at boot would have to be relaxed security and every single macOS update it would get overwritten or fail. Assuming you got the modified OS to run, next update it starts fresh.

The steps to alter this vary based on your hardware in addition to the version of macOS. The short answer, is no.

Better to work on automating changing the preferences for each app you allow to sound the notification rather than work on your proposed OS alteration.

Comment: While I appreciate that this is the only way to "solve" this problem right now, I'm still holding out hope that *somewhere* there's a setting I can tweak...

Comment: Understood @naydichev - you’ve asked in the perfect spot for someone to show up with an answer if one is discovered or implemented. There has to be code somewhere that names the default so that too could become discoverable, configurable or variable at some point.